# flash game wmode=transparent alternative

Tags: flash, wmode

I need to embed some flash games but I'm disallowed to use wmode=transparent due to performance issues & sideFX. I need to place a DIV above the SWF, but without the wmode the SWF is always on top.

Hiding the swf when div is visible resets the flash.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `wmode=transparent`, I think you are out of luck for positioning HTML over the swf.

However, if you were willing to *hide* the flash, maybe you can try positioning the flash off screen with CSS `position:absolute;left:-99999px` to get the same effect.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the creative idea. I am wondering, isn't iframe supposed to be above flash? maybe I can get both object to be included withing an iframe and then set different zindex to both

Comment: its worth a shot. ive never tried that so i am not sure how the two would interact with each other. my gut says it wont work since flash is a browser plugin and probably takes priority. only one way to ffind out though!

Comment: Well, the final solution was to change the height of the parent div. It doesn't make the flash to reload.